# How can I get the JQuery Tooltip to display when I hover over an item on a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The [tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) works for about everything else except drop down items.

What am I doing wrong

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('option').each(function(){
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
    //$('option').tooltip();
});
```

edit: my html is pretty basic at the moment http://jsfiddle.net/kasfu/

**edit** I want the tooltip to show when I hover over an item on the dropdown list

Comment: could you show your html as well please

Comment: @Eric ive added a link to what my select looks like. but i don't think jsfiddle has picked up that i am using the tooltip plugin

Comment: its working in chrome.... What's your question?

Comment: working in Firefox (18) too ... but I did notice the tooltips are hidden behind the drop down list.

Comment: @Vinay it doesn't work. the tooltip you see there is the standard tooltip not the jquery tooltip

Comment: @Marijn  the tooltip you see there is the standard tooltip not the jquery tooltip

Comment: The tooltip that's showing is [from jquery-ui](http://grabilla.com/03205-46de70c1-4dff-4a94-9225-4765c3abbec9.png). Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: @adam are you seeing a yellow tooltip that disappears after 5-10seconds? if so, then that's bnot the jquery tooltip its the browser's default tooltip

Comment: [No, I am 100% seeing the jquery-ui tooltip](http://grabilla.com/03205-92e5e21b-8348-449c-8890-008c8dc8ff21.png)

Comment: @adam can you post your updated jsfiddle please

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/kasfu/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/kasfu/3/) - What browser are you using?

Comment: @user521180 your code is working fine in Mozilla... not in chrome

Comment: @adam I'm using chrome 24.0.1312.57  and all I see is the default yellow tooltip. the client is using IE7 and it's not working there either

Comment: Its working on FF. But: the TT shows behind the drop down, the drop-down isn't actually an HTML element but an OS control. You need to use some HTML/CSS styled drop-down instead of that because the standard drop-down will almost everywhere go on top.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, it has nothing to do with your code. It's a known issue, and one that doesn't look like it will be fixed (any time soon anyway). The tooltip does work in chrome, however webkit browsers don't like tooltips on `option` elements.

[See here for the bug ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8708)

I guess you have three solutions that I can think of.

1. Find a different / Build your own tooltip plugin that does work.
2. Use a `<ul>` and style it to look like a drop-down, and add some jQuery to control the show/hide
3. Just stick with the browsers standard tooltip.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your tooltip plugin link.
I guess, it depends on `jquery.dimensions.js and jquery.bgiframe.js`
from the demo page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you need..

```
<select>
    <option title="1" >1</option>
    <option title="2">2</option>
    <option title="3">3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('option').each(function(){
        $(this).style.top = window.event.clientY + 20;
        $(this).style.left = window.event.clientX;
        $(this).style.display = 'block';
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
$('option').each(function(index, element){
        $(element).tooltip({ content: "<div>Select an Item</div>", track: true});
    });
```